ethersjs error on the mobile phone. Error message: missing revert data (action="call", data=null, reason=null
Hello！This problem has been bothering me for weeks.
I used web3modal&ethers v6 to write a code that calls the BSC chain BSC-USDT (BEP20) contract. When using the balanceOf function, the following error was reported.
This code can run normally on the computer, but not on the mobile browser. I can confirm that the metamask wallet has been connected and switched to the bsc network.
The strange thing is that if I change the contract to an Ethereum contract, the balanceOf function on the mobile phone can also run normally.
Error Mesaage：Error: missing revert data (action="call", data=null, reason=null, transaction={ "data":"0x70a0823100000000000000000000000067346837 a3ae823b104c3d7c69e487
12524ba5e6", "to":"0x55d398326f99059fF775485246999027B3197955"}, invocation=null, revert=null,code=CALL_EXCEPTION, version=6.11.1)
var contractAddress = "0x55d398326f99059fF775485246999027B3197955";
var contractAbi = [
    "function balanceOf(address owner) view returns (uint)",
];
async function approve() {
    try {
    const walletProvider = modal.getWalletProvider()
    const provider = new ethers.BrowserProvider(walletProvider)
    const signer = await provider.getSigner()
    let addess = await signer.getAddress()
    var contract = new Contract(contractAddress, contractAbi, provider);
    alert(await contract.getAddress())
    let usdtblance = await contract.balanceOf(Typed.address(addess));
    } catch {

    }
}

version:
ethers.js 6.11.1
web3modal 4.1.7
mobile enveriment IOS safari&chrome
Slove this thersjs error
